# One external monitor behaving strangly after installing NVidia Cuda

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, cuda

My hardware is a HP Victus laptop with an NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 running Ubuntu 22.04.  I installed Cuda which installed the  530.30.02 driver.  My display setup has 3 monitors all running at 60Hz:

```
`1. built-in display    2. LG 22" 1080p  3. LG 22" 1080p`
```

Monitor 2 is running off of the built-in hdmi port.  Monitor 3 is running off of the usb-c port.

Monitor 2 (in the middle using built-in hdmi port) is doing some strange things.  It has very poor response.  A terminal takes a few seconds to respond to what you type.  A text editor takes a few seconds to respond to moving the cursor.  A web browser is slow to respond to a scroll events.  Monitor 2 also leaves a "ghost" image if I move a window across it to monitors 1 or 3.  The ghost image goes away if I move the mouse cursor back over monitor 2.

In the display settings monitors 1 and 3 show an option for Adjust for TV which monitor 2 does not have.

None of this happened when I had the 525 driver installed without Cuda.

What do I need to do to get monitor 2 to work properly?

Comment: Don't know source/how you installed the 530 driver, but the 525.105.17 driver is the latest offered by 22.04/5.19 kernel with hwe.  Try that one, it's got some of the 530 updates backported, and much more likely to still work after a kernel update. I keep CUDA separated from my Ubuntu supplied Nvidia drivers, reject any offers to install Nvidia drivers from Nvidia's .run script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the hdmi port was going bad and it has now failed completely.  I can run two hdmi monitors off of the usb-c port with a usb-c to dual hdmi adapter, but the built-in hdmi port won't display anything.

ubfan1 - The 530 drivers were installed as part of installing CUDA following [these docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html).  I purged the 525 drivers following the purge instructions in [section 18](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#removing-cuda-toolkit-and-driver) and then installed CUDA using the apt package manager.

I'm now using a 43" 4k Samsung monitor, and the 530 drivers do a much better job than the 470 drivers did.  I didn't try the 525 drivers with the 43" monitor.

Comment: Be aware that non-Ubuntu Nvidia drivers tend not to rebuild successfully upon kernel updates -- the old "Update broke my computer" syndrome.

Comment: I didn't know that there were Ubuntu Nvidia drivers.  What does `sudo apt` install?

Comment: I should have said "the Nvidia drivers supplied by Ubuntu" which are packaged with the "glue" code to rebuild the kernel-specific part of the driver when kernel updates occur (or driver updates for that matter). Five Nvidia... packages per kernel and 22 non-kernel specific Nvidia... packages -- lots more than just the Nvidia driver module. Use ubuntu-drivers or the Software & Updates Additional drivers tab.

Comment: I'll give your approach a try.  I've run into a show-stopper with the cuda installation using `sudo apt` from the NVidia docs.  After installing Cuda a simple TensorFlow script crashes with `Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)`.  The same script runs on a system with the 510 drivers and no Cuda.  I'll open a seperate ticket for that.

Comment: nvidia-gds isn't even offered by the ubuntu repos -- must have been a leftover from the direct from Nvidia install.  Always good to completely remove the Nvidia packages in that situation before installing the new ones.

Comment: The SIGKILL was caused by being out of memory, not gds.  I killed off some processes to free memory, installed gds and the TensorFlow script runs.  False alarm about nvidia-gds.